# Excel VBA Recordset is empty

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

i have an ADODB recordset to load data from a view in an Excel sheet. The view is located in a MS SQL database. It runs perfectly for months, but since a few days the recordset is always empty, so i did not get any results. After a long day searching the www for any reasons i found, that it can happen because i use a x32 Excel and there is so much data in the view. So i separated the procedure in two queries. This helped a lot and the macro run perfectly again. Yesterday the same error appears again, so i began to split the procedure again. But now the recordset is still empty. I don't know any reason for this. I tested it with a selection of only ten rows of the view and this runs but if i want to get 1000 rows the recordset is empty again. Does anybody know a reason for this problem? All queries give the result i want to have in the database so they are ok.

Here is my code:

```
Sub doStuff()
    Dim sqlStatement(9) As String
    Dim lrow As Long 
    '... other variables

    sqlStatement(1) = "Select * from db.View1 where location like 'forest'"
    '... other sqlStatements
    For i = 0 To UBound(sqlStatement)
        Call loadData(sqlStatement, lrow)
    Next i 
End Sub 

Sub loadData(sqlStatement As String, lastrow As Long)
    Dim sqlServer As String 
    Dim dbName As String 

    sqlServer = "MSSQLSERVER"
    dbName = "database"

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim con As Object
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    con.Open _
        "Provider = sqloledb;" & _
        "Data Source=" & sqlServer & ";" & _
        "Initial Catalog=" & dbName & ";" & _
        "User ID=user1;" & _
        "Password=abcde;"


    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    With rst
        .ActiveConnection = con
        .Open sqlStatement , con, adLockReadOnly
        ws.Activate
        If lastrow = 1 Then 
            For col = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
                ws.Cells(1, col + 1).Value = .Fields(col).Name
            Next
        End If 
        ws.Activate
        ws.Cells(lastrow+1,1).CopyFromRecordset rst
        .Close
    End With

    con.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `On Error Resume Next` from `loadData`, at least temporarily?  This statement is capable of hiding the true issue, by suppressing all error messages.  Also, approximately how many records are you expecting?

Comment: Yes, it could be an issue with the connection that's skipped each time.   If you're passing con, no need to set it.

Comment: Thank you! I get a runtime error ('-2147217871 (80040e31)') - Query timeout expired. All in all over 17500 rows  and 135 columns.  But if i only select a part of the view (something like 1000 rows) the recordset is still empty and this error also appears, while select only 10 rows from the view.

Comment: But if i have the "On Error Resume Next" statement in the code, i get the selection of ten rows from the view. So what else could it be?

Comment: Try creating an ADO.Command object and set a timeout value. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142139/vba-ado-connection-timeout-in-different-version-of-libraries

Comment: Thank you! I didn't create an ado command, but use the   CommandTimeout property. I added the line 'con.CommandTimeout = 0  ' and the problem was solved.